# Can the inner product of two negative vectors be negative?

Tags: inner-products

Today the TA for my quantum mechanics class told me that the inner product $\langle-x|-x\rangle=-1$. This makes no sense to me and I've never heard of this before (that I can remember). How could this possibly be true when the inner product is $\langle f,g\rangle := \int_a^bf(t)g(t)dt$? She told me "when you dot a negative vector with another negative vector it stays in the $-x$ plane." That I could potentially see making sense, but I don't see how this could possibly be true when you look at the integral form of the inner product.

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative vector"? To me, this has not sense.

Comment: Angle brackets are written using `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @Gödel Sorry, I suppose it's not the right term... but by "negative vector" I meant the $-\vec x$. I'm used to doing dot products with vectors, so I suppose that's just stuck with me.

Comment: Your TA is ridiculously wrong. The idea of a "negative vector" itself doesn't make much sense here, but inner products are (by definition) linear: $\langle{-x|-x\rangle} = (-1)^2 \langle{x|x}\rangle$. Also, the norm $\langle{x|x\rangle}$ is non-negative, again by definition.